# Finding (orthogonal) idempotents in a quotient of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, idempotents

I wish to identify all of the non-trivial idempotents in the ring
$$ \Bbbk[x]/\langle x(x+1)^2(x+2)^2(x+3)\rangle.$$ 
I have reason to suspect that there are at least four which are, in addition, pairwise orthogonal. So far, I've found 
$$
\frac{-1}{12}x(x+1)^2(x+2)^2 \\ \frac{1}{12}(x+1)^2(x+2)^2(x+3) \\ \frac{1}{4}(x+1)^2(x+2)^2,
$$
where the first two are orthogonal, and the last one is their sum. Additionally, the difference between 1 and any of the above gives an idempotent. Is there a good strategy for identifying any others, or perhaps a good way to get a computer to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to find the primitive idempotents, i.e. the idempotents which cannot be decomposed into a sum of orthogonal idempotents in a nontrivial way. All other idempotents are sums of primitive idempotents.

The Chinese Remainder Theorem can help finding the primitive idempotents. Note that
$$ \mathbb{k}[X]/(X(X+1)^2(X+2)^2(X+3))\\ \cong \mathbb{k}[X]/X \times \mathbb{k}[X]/(X+1)^2 \times \mathbb{k}[X]/(X+2)^2 \times \mathbb{k}[X]/(X+3)\\\cong \mathbb{k} \times \mathbb{k}[X]/X^2 \times \mathbb{k}[X]/X^2 \times \mathbb{k}.$$

So you only have to find the primitive idempotents of the direct factors and to apply these isomorphisms to them.

Comment: That seems useful. Having found the primitive idempotents in each ring in the product, how does one find the corresponding element in the original ring?

Comment: You have to apply the isomorphism given by the Chinese Remainder Theorem to them.

Comment: The proof of the CRT that I'm familiar with gives an isomorphism 
$$\mathbb{k}[X]/(X(X+1)^2(X+2)^2(X+3)) \to \mathbb{k}[X]/X \times \mathbb{k}[X]/(X+1)^2 \times \mathbb{k}[X]/(X+2)^2 \times \mathbb{k}[X]/(X+3)$$, and then shows well-definedness and bijectivity, but doesn't construct an inverse explicitly.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, each term in the product contains two idempotents, 0 and 1, and these give rise to $2^4 = 16$ primitive idempotents in the original ring. (As a side note, the idempotents which are mapped under the CRT to $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)$ turned out to be the ones I wanted.) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice case since all idempotents in the factor rings given by CRT are trivial, that is, $0$ and $1$, so you only have to find which polynomial corresponds to the idempotent $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,0)$, $(0,0,1,0)$, respectively $(0,0,0,1)$.
For $(1,0,0,0)$ take $\frac{1}{12}(x+1)^2(x+2)^2(x+3)$.
For $(0,1,0,0)$ we get $\frac{1}{4}x(x+2)^2(x+3)(3x+1)$.

I leave you the pleasure to find the other two.

Comment: For completion's sake, the other two are $-\frac{1}{4}x(x+1)^2(x+3)(3x+8)$ and $-\frac{1}{12}x(x+1)^2(x+2)^2$.

Comment: @ user26857: Is there a quick method for obtaining these polynomials? It took more effort than I would have liked!